# Laravel Passport Grant password stopped to work after 11 upgrade

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

After my upgrade from passport 9 to 11 and laravel 9 to 10 oauth/token route always return **page is expired** error.

I followed documentation and changed passport routes from defined to route list.

Nothing more was change, I am sending the same payload like before when it worked, it also meets with documentation.

Any ideas?